# Is there a way to retrieve User data from sys_updated_by field on Incident/Task?

Tags: javascript, servicenow

Is there an out-of-box/best-practice solution to retrieve a user object from the Updated By (sys_updated_by) field on the Incident/Task table?

I know a workaround would be to create a custom field on Task pointing to the User table, type Reference. Then create a custom business rule to set the field on "Insert/Update". Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1):

current.sys_updated_by does not reference further User data of who updated the record. current.sys_updated_by is a string value that contains the string value originating from user_name.sys_user on the sys_user table.

It is however possible to use "current.sys_updated_by" with in your Notification or business rule to get further information of the user that updated the record

this can be done by executing another glide query with in the Mail script/Business Rule/Notification etc.

For example:

```
var userdata = new GlideRecord("sys_user");

     userdata.addQuery('user_name', current.sys_updated_by);   
     userdata.query();

      while (userdata.next()) { 
      var email = userdata.email; // Will give you the email of the user
      }
```

Where "userdata" is the array values for the entire user record.

Comment: You need to be more specific on what the problem/issue is. What is userdata? Give an example. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your question in context. What are you trying to accomplish?

If you are in a server script (*e.g.* Business Rule) then it is quite easy. If `current` is your GlideRecord for **Task** or **Incident**, and you need a GlideRecord for **sys_user** then the code is.

```js
var grUser = new GlideRecord('sys_user');
if (grUser.get('user_name', current.sys_updated_by)) {
    // do something with grUser
}
```

If you have reporting needs that require you to drill through to pick up user attributes of the last person who updated a task, then you can add a custom field to the **Task** table and maintain it with a Business Rule.

As a side note, there is a reason why `sys_updated_on` is not a **sys_id**. It is possible that the last person to update an object is not a user in your instance. They could have been a user in another instance and the object was updated in your instance via XML or an Update Set.